# jfilechooser, save multiples file ,image?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I want to make jfilechooser select multiple types, but I get an error in my fileinputstream like in below:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        JFileChooser ch = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
        int c = ch.showOpenDialog(this);
        ch.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        ch.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        ch.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        if (c == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File[] f = ch.getSelectedFiles();


            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(); 
            /// the error start from in here
            byte b[] = new byte[in.available()];
            in.read(b);
            Data data = new Data();
            lblNewLabel.setText(ch.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            data.setName(lblNewLabel.getText().trim());
            data.setFile(b);
            out.writeObject(data);
            out.flush();
            textArea.append("send 1 file ../n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e, "Error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}`
```

can everyone fix it?

Comment: please post your error stack trace. And why would you ask for multiple files, but not use them ? File[] f

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `.getSelectedFile()` method, although you have selected multiple files.

You have to use `.getSelectedFiles()` method like in line 9 of your code sample and iterate through the `File[]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(); 
    /// the error start from in here
    byte b[] = new byte[in.available()];
    in.read(b);
```

The instantiation of **FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream()** is wrong. As **nvplus** said you have to select ONE file and instantiate it as following

```
File f = ch.getSelectedFile();
FileInputStream in = FileInputStream(f); // <---
```